# Web Client Android

Tags: android

I'm new at Android and I want to develop an app where I share news or events from my city, something like this image.

[image]

Several tabs where I will set News Events and others things. Also I would like to implement a map where you can find some tourist routes, good places to eat and more.

Each item will be some kind of new event which will appear on the blue square detailed.

I know how to implement this interface my question is how to update the info daily. Should I use webclientview or a web service and use ksoap. I'm a bit lost and I don't know where to start or what exactly to search for, some kind of tutorials which you guys recommend I would be really thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever you use will be fine. Maybe using web service with a listview to display the events will be more customizable than the other option.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Im also thinking about JSON what do you think? What is the best aproach?

Comment: it all depends on the time you have and your requirements. Using a web service, ksoap or xmlrpc or whatever, will require more work, but you will be able to customize the ui. With webview you will show a web page. The info will be the same and you will have to work less. Anyway, if you want to make an elegant application, you should use a web service.

Comment: if you use web service, you should use listview with custom rows for each event. You could take advantage of some libraries like https://github.com/shontauro/android-pulltorefresh-and-loadmore in order to make the list of events refreshable and to not overload data connections.

Comment: I will go with the web service then. Thank you for your time and help Luciano really appreciated.

Comment: you are wellcome, if you have more doubts i'll be here =)